# iptables shows that esp line is not used while packages are correctly processed

Tags: ipsec, iptables

I setup an IPsec ESP connection between a test laptop and an embedded device, in transport mode.
Below, i show the iptables of the embedded device.
As the rules indicate, icmp traffic is allowed, and when I do a ping from my test laptop to the embedded device, this is indeed working.

What I find strange is that although the incoming ping messages are processed by the embedded device (rule 13 indicates that 9 packets were processed), the ESP rule (rule 30) indicates that no ESP packets have been processed. I find this strange behavior that I cannot explain.
The outgoing ping replies, this behavior seems to be correct, 9 ESP packets and also 9 icmp packets allowed by the ipsec policy.

Can somebody explain why on the incoming side while it seems as if no ESP packets are processed while there is indeed communication protected by IPsec?
I am 100% sure that ESP packets are sent to the embedded device (checked with wireshark)

Much thanks in advance for your feedback!

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 102 packets, 12012 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
13       9   756 ACCEPT     icmp --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            policy match dir in pol ipsec mode transport        
30       0     0 ACCEPT     esp  --  eth0   *       192.168.104.20       192.168.104.10      
31       0     0 ACCEPT     ah   --  eth0   *       192.168.104.20       192.168.104.10      
32      18  2525 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   *       192.168.104.20       192.168.104.10       udp dpt:500
33       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   *       192.168.104.20       192.168.104.10       udp dpt:4500

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 112 packets, 23752 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
6        9   756 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            policy match dir out pol ipsec mode transport
22       0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
23       9   972 ACCEPT     esp  --  *      eth0    192.168.104.10       192.168.104.20      
24       0     0 ACCEPT     ah   --  *      eth0    192.168.104.10       192.168.104.20      
25      18  2520 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      eth0    192.168.104.10       192.168.104.20       udp spt:500
26       0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      eth0    192.168.104.10       192.168.104.20       udp spt:4500


Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```